# Address to WCHAR_T to pass to ReadProcessMemory

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I'm having trouble passing a `WCHAR_T` to `ReadProcessMemory`

This is how to succesfully pass a pointers address to `ReadProcessMemory`, I can do it with structures:

```
    remote_tbb = ralloc_alloc(struct_TBButton.size);
    var rez = SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_GETBUTTON, i, ctypes.voidptr_t(remote_tbb));
    if (!rez) { throw new Error('Failed on SendMessage of TB_GETBUTTON') }

    var local_tbb = new struct_TBButton();
    var retRead = ralloc_read(remote_tbb, local_tbb.address());
    var freed = ralloc_free(remote_tbb);
```

But now I need to do with `WCHAR_T`, so this is what I have:

```
    var chars = SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, local_tbb.idCommand, ctypes.voidptr_t(0));
    console.log('chars=', chars, chars.toString(), uneval(chars));

    if (chars && parseInt(chars.toString()) > 0) {
        var remote_buf = ralloc_alloc(parseInt(chars.toString()));
        var charsRe = SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, local_tbb.idCommand, ctypes.voidptr_t(remote_buf));
        console.log('charsRe=', charsRe);

        var local_buf = ctypes.jschar; //WCHAR_T
        var retRead = ralloc_read(remote_buf, local_buf.address()); ///PROBLEM LINE
        console.log('retRead=', retRead);

        var freed = ralloc_free(remote_buf);
        console.log('freed=', freed);

        console.log('Button Text = ', local_buf, local_buf.toString());
    } else {
        console.log('Button Text = NONE');
    }
```

So my problem is on line:

```
var retRead = ralloc_read(remote_buf, local_buf.address());`
```

and it is specifically on the `local_buf.address()`

Errors in my experimenting that get thrown are:

- `expected type pointer, got ctypes.jschar`
- `local_buf.address is not a function`

So how to pass `WCHAR_T` as reference?

Edit:
Here is my `ralloc_read` implemetnation:

```
function ralloc_read(remote_address, local_buffer) {
    var found_addr;
    for (var i = 0; i < buffers.length; i++) {
        if (buffers[i][0] == remote_address) {
            found_addr = buffers[i]
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found_addr) {
        return null;
    }
    /*using the found remote address(found_addr[0]), 
     *i read size bytes (found_addr[1]) into my local_buffer*/
    //console.info('found_addr[0]', found_addr[0].toString());
    var rez = ReadProcessMemory(proc, found_addr[0], local_buffer, found_addr[1], 0);
    return rez;
}
```

Comment: Try to change `local_buf.address()` to `local_buf.ptr`

Comment: What's your implementation of `ralloc_read`?

Comment: @paa, thanks for thank I tried it I got this error: `Exception: expected type pointer, got ctypes.jschar.ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ralloc_read` calls `ReadProcessMemory`, then you'll need to allocate a `jschar` array that will receive the result.

```
var local_buf = ctypes.jschar.array()(chars);
ralloc_read(remote_buf, local_buf.address());
var str = local_buf.readString();
```

*Edit* However, the allocation call is wrong:

```
ralloc_alloc(parseInt(chars.toString()));
```

This will allocate `chars` bytes, e.g. `chars = 11`, 11 bytes.
A `wchar_t`/`jschar` however is not 1 byte but 2 bytes.

```
ctypes.jschar.size
// 2
```

So you'll actually need to allocate a remote memory buffer that is larger:

```
ralloc_alloc(parseInt(chars.toString()) * ctypes.jschar.size);
// That would be ralloc_alloc(count * sizeof(wchar_t*)) in C/C++
```

The `local_buf` stuff is correct, though as js-ctypes arrays will automatically calculate the required storage if it knows the size of the array element type, so a `ctypes.jschar.array()(11)` buffer will actually have 11 elements of size 2 bytes, i.e. `11 items * 2 bytes/item == 22 bytes`.

Comment: Wow it works!! I'm not doing it right though as it's not reading the whole thing, What type should `chars` be? Btw: I edited in my `realloc_read` above. :)

Comment: The reason I'm not doing it right is when I do `console.log('Button Text = ', local_buf, local_buf.toString(), local_buf.readString());` on a button with text of `*Scratchpad` i get `"Button Text = " CData { length: 11 } "ctypes.jschar.array(11)(["*", "S", "c", "r", "a", "t", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00"])" "*Scrat"`. It's length is correct at 11 but it only gets first 6 characters in the `readString, the `toString` has 11 entries but after the first 6 they are all messed up as `\x00`. :(

Comment: `\x00` == `0` == "null". `.readString` interprets the array as a null-terminated string (aka. c-string), and `TB_GETBUTTONTEXT` actually returns a null-terminated string. So the results here are correct. I edited my answer regarding `wchar_t` and why your stuff is truncated (actually the code did not crash the `explorer.exe` process only because `VirtualAllocEx` allocates full-pages)